# Error with value of identifiers C Programming

Tags: c

Alright, I am making a fairly basic program which reads from account.txt. The output ends up looking like how I would expect it to except the values of amount and balance are displayed as 0.00.

Here is the account.txt file:

```
I 478.83
D 127.45
D 619.84
C 945.12
C   4.76
D  32.81
C   1.06
D 184.32
C 495.18
C 141.81
C 255.10
D 250.00
D 123.88
D 245.05
D 873.25
C 981.12
D 317.84
C 812.73
D 606.12
```

Here is the relevant part of my program.

```
int process_info(void){

char code;

double amount, service, balance;

double amtCheck, amtDeposit, openBalance, closeBalance;

int numCheck, numDeposit, numOverdraft;


amount = 0.0;
service = 0.0;
balance = 0.0;
amtCheck = 0.0;
amtDeposit = 0.0;
openBalance = 0.0;
closeBalance = 0.0;
numCheck = 0;
numDeposit = 0;

fp = fopen("account.txt", "r");

printf("Transaction\tDeposit\tCheck\tBalance\n");
printf("-----------\t-------\t-----\t-------\n");

while ((fscanf(fp, "%c %f", &code, &amount)) != EOF){
    if (code == 'I'){
        openBalance = amount;
        balance += amount;
        printf("Initial Balance\t\t\t%.2f\n", amount);
    }
    else if (code == 'D'){
        numDeposit++;
        balance += amount;
        printf("Deposit\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\n", amount, balance);
    }
    else if (code == 'C'){
        numCheck++;
        balance -= amount;
        printf("Check\t\t\t%.2f\t%.2f\n", amount, balance);
    }
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fscanf` returns the number of successful conversions made - check that and see if the call is working the way you expect (hint: it's not).

Turning on some warnings would be a good first step.  The `%f` format you're using in the `fscanf()` call doesn't match the `double *` argument you're assing.  Use `%lf`.  From [clang](http://clang.llvm.org):

```
example.c:29:36: warning: format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has
      type 'double *' [-Wformat]
while ((fscanf(fp, "%c %f", &code, &amount)) != EOF){
                       ~~          ^~~~~~~
                       %lf
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean in the first paragraph, the program stops right at the end of account.txt. I changed the %f to %lf and all my values are being outputted properly now. Thank You! I probably do have some more errors to work through ;).